# Can i get data inside web browser from android sharedpreferences?

Tags: javascript, android, web

I am developing an application for android in which I storing some data to shared preferences.
Now My question is can i fetch that data inside a web browser on same device??

```
For example:
when i run my application 
I have stored something like this :
Key :User_Email
Value:abc@abc.com
```

and then close the application.

Now i am on android web browser and open my webpage on which i have added a button,On Clicking this Button I am trying to get that value from shared preferences.

Please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet and android application are different things.

You can't do this directly, due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below example code:

```
String html = sharedPref.getString("KEY");
String mime = "text/html";
String encoding = "UTF-8";

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);
```

Comment: hi iTech thanks for your answer,But i am not getting this properly ..can you please explore your answer?